# SSRS conditional formatting column with alternating row highlighting and NULL handling

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, conditional-formatting, iif

I have an SSRS report where I'm supposed to conditionally format a column red/green depending on if an expression is  +/- 5% (less is good, so less is green).  I also need to have the entire report have alternating row highlighting.  I can get these to function correctly until I throw in some NULL handling.

```
=Switch
(
IsNothing(Sum(Fields!August2015.Value)),IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "#d9d9d9", "Transparent"),
(Fields!August2015.Value-Fields!CorporateAvg.Value)/Fields!CorporateAvg.Value >= .05, "Pink", 
(Fields!August2015.Value-Fields!CorporateAvg.Value)/Fields!CorporateAvg.Value <= -.05, "LightGreen",
(Fields!August2015.Value-Fields!CorporateAvg.Value)/Fields!CorporateAvg.Value > -.05 And 
(Fields!August2015.Value-Fields!CorporateAvg.Value)/Fields!CorporateAvg.Value < .05, IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "#d9d9d9", "Transparent")
)
```

It looks like the issue is that once something is green or red the alternating row highlighting resets and throws the rest of the rows off.  Here's an example:

[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13aT1.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is around the section

```
IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "#d9d9d9", "Transparent")
```

As no scope has been set it is not clear when the row count is reset to zero.  You cold always see what this rownumber value is by temporarily adding a second expression to the cell to show just the `RowNumber(Nothing)` value

Have you tried using `CountDistinct` and `RunningValue` instead (assuming you have a unique value per row).  For example, replacing the noted section above with

```
IIf(RunningValue(CountDistinct(Fields!Serial.Value), Sum, "DataSet1") mod 2), "#d9d9d9", "Transparent")
```

This is then based on the dataset you are reading and the sort order of the results, and not just the order of the rows as they appear on the report itself.

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution.  I'm getting an error when I implement it:

Overload resolution failed because no  accessible "IIf" accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I hit Enter without realizing it would post my comment.  I edited my comment above.

Comment: I got it to run by removing the parenthesis after the mod 2, but it doesn't seem to work propertly:  [http://imgur.com/14Vy0jZ](http://imgur.com/14Vy0jZ)

Comment: Did you attempt to add the second expression to the cell showing RowNumber(Nothing)?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to add a second expression to the cell.

Comment: Your cell probably has something like <<Expr>> in it already.  You can move the cursor to the end of this, then right click and select 'Create Placeholder' to allow you to add another expression

Comment: Thanks for that info!  I'll use that in the future.  It's still not working.  It's pulling back the correct rownumber (1,2,3,4...).  I feel like there's a scenario that I haven't accounted for, but I can't figure it out.  Here's my new code (I added a OddEvenForHighlighting column in the SQL to do that row numbering on the database side: (((I added this new code to my original post)))