# Apply different formatting to different columns in a column group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have some summary data, by year, that I am displaying in a tablix, in a pivot table fashion.  The first column is the year, each row is a single year, and each column contains counts and dollar amounts from a query.

[image]

By default all of the value columns are formatted the same way.  However, I need the first 4 columns formatted as a whole number (total counts) and the last 2 columns formatted as currency or 2 decimal places with commas.  As shown here, my counts have .00 that I don't want shown.

[image]

Comment: Hows is this different from other conditional formatting questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538222/ssrs-conditional-formatting-switch-or-iif or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502221/ssrs-conditional-formatting-column-with-alternating-row-highlighting-and-null-ha?

Comment: I was trying to apply the expression to the Number format property, did not realize I could format it from the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something that will get you going in the right direction:

```
=IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "Claims Filed" OR Fields!Type.Value = "Claims Approved", FormatNumber(Fields!Value.Value, 0), FormatCurrency(Fields!Value.Value, 2))
```

You will have to fill in for the other options, or switch these around to use the money values in the first part of the `IIf` since it is the shorter list. But, this should give you a good idea of how this can be done.

It is just a simple matter of conditional formatting, SSRS style.

Comment: Made a slight change, but you got me going in the right direction.  I thought I had to reference the Type field a different way but it's just a value on the row.    

    =IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "Claims Filed" OR Fields!Type.Value = "Claims Approved" OR Fields!Type.Value = "Claims Denied" OR Fields!Type.Value = "Claims Paid", Format(Sum(Fields!Value.Value),"#,###.##"), Format(Sum(Fields!Value.Value),"$ #,###.##"))